# css transitions pushing elements

Tags: html, css

i am trying to make a new menu for my site and i'm using transitions on highlight.

but i am getting some issues with elements being pushed around. for example if you highlight Home it will push all elements to right of it. 
however if there are 2 lines it will not push the element down. instead it will just mask it. how can i make sure each element has it's own dedicated space and not be pushed and also not be masked.

I tried making an absolute with an inner relative but that didn't work.

http://jsfiddle.net/yg68cnnt/

Html:

```
<ul> 
    <li> Home </li>
    <li> About </li>
    <li> FAQ </li>
    <li> Locations </li>
    <li> StackOverflow </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul{
    list-style-type:none;
    position:absolute;
}


li{
    display:inline;
    transition: all 2s;
    width:0px;
    position:relative;
    margin-right:3em;
    padding-top:10px;
    padding-right:30px;
    padding-left:4px;
}

li:hover{
    background-color:red;
    border-right:20px solid black;
    border-bottom:20px solid black;
    border-bottom-right-radius:10px;
    border-top-left-radius:10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the border to grow, you can trick it by using css3 `box-shadow` with blur set to 0 instead of using `border`, because shadow does not cause the element itself to grow.

```
li:hover{    
    background-color:red;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 0 10px black;
    border-bottom-right-radius:10px;
    border-top-left-radius:10px;
}
```

(Note that it is probably a hack and not the most correct way to solve your problem. It sort of works though.)

Vertical space between items can be achieved by setting `display` to `inline-block` and setting `margin-bottom`:

```
li{
    display:inline-block;
    margin-bottom:2em;

    transition: all 2s;
    position:relative;
    margin-right:3em;        
    padding-top:10px;
    padding-right:30px;
    padding-left:4px;
}
```

[updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yg68cnnt/7/)

Comment: this way keeps the transition animation. the other answers don't.

Answer (score 0):

You could set a transparent border on the non-hover state like this:

```
li {
    display:inline;
    transition: all 2s;
    width:0px;
    position:relative;
    margin-right:3em;
    padding-top:10px;
    padding-right:30px;
    padding-left:4px;
    border-right:20px solid transparent;
    border-bottom:20px solid transparent;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/yg68cnnt/2/)**